# Cleaning raster data

Tags: qgis, raster

I have biocenosis data (coralligenous, dead mat and seagrass). I'd now like to clean it up and start by getting rid of the coralligenous data. Basically, I have a raster with 4 bands as you can see on the screenshot attached. Do you know how I could remove the coralligenous data (pink), and have two distinct categories for dead matte (yellow-orange) and seagrass (light green)?

[image]

Comment: Is there just one single RGB-color value for each color or are there different, very similar values? In the first case, you could use reclassify or raster calculator.

Comment: I thought about that, but there are different very similar values...